# bufferline.nvim does not configure with packer.nvim

Tags: neovim

I want bufferline.nvim configured such that the buffers get offset when nvim-tree gets expanded. However, configuring it with the [documentation](https://github.com/akinsho/bufferline.nvim) didn't have any effect.

Some more testing revealed that none of the options were taking effect. See MRE below. Most noticeably, the separator style remains default.

[Image: Neovim after applying MRE below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1QNT.png)

`init.lua`

```lua
require("user.plugins")

vim.g.loaded_netrw = 1
vim.g.loaded_netrwPlugin = 1

require("nvim-tree").setup({
    view = {
        adaptive_size = true
    }
})

vim.keymap.set('n', '<c-n>', ':NvimTreeFindFileToggle<CR>')

vim.opt.termguicolors = true

require("bufferline").setup({
  options = {
    separator_style = {"AAAA", "AAAA"},
    hover = {
      enabled = true,
      delay = 200,
      reveal = {"close"}
    },
    offsets = {
      {
        filetype = "NvimTree",
        text = "File Explorer",
        highlight = "Directory",
        separator = true
      }
    }
  }
})
```

`lua/user/plugins.lua`

```lua
-- This code is exactly the same as the documentation provided at https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim#bootstrapping, except with plugins specified
local ensure_packer = function()
    local fn = vim.fn
    local install_path = fn.stdpath('data')..'/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim'
    if fn.empty(fn.glob(install_path)) > 0 then
      fn.system({'git', 'clone', '--depth', '1', 'https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim', install_path})
      vim.cmd [[packadd packer.nvim]]
      return true
    end
    return false
  end
  
  local packer_bootstrap = ensure_packer()
  
  return require('packer').startup(function(use)
    use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'
    -- My plugins here
    use 'nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua'
    use 'nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons'
    use 'akinsho/bufferline.nvim'
  
    -- Automatically set up your configuration after cloning packer.nvim
    -- Put this at the end after all plugins
    if packer_bootstrap then
      require('packer').sync()
    end
  end)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: The configurations were being overridden by a different extension `barbar` which, despite being removed for the MRE, was cached at `~/.local/share/nvim`. The configured options are taking effect after deleting the cache.